# Unable to read data from JAXBElement<byte[]>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am accessing one of the web-services from our vendor which takes a pageID and returns data in xml format.

When I access the web-service on browser, the format of xml after I key in pageID is as below

```
<EpsBinaryEx xmlns="http://Eprise">
<ErrorString>No Error</ErrorString>
<ErrorNum>1</ErrorNum>
<Data>ajhsdjasjajadjhgasd</Data>
</EpsBinaryEx>
```

Am interested in retrieving the  element. This is actually a Base64 string. I have a method for EpsBinaryEx which is returning data in below form

```
 public JAXBElement<byte[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

Using Java, am reading the webservice as below

```
PSWebService service = new PSWebService();                   
PSWebServiceSoap soap = service.getPSWebServiceSoap();
EpsBinaryEx base64Data = soap.getUploadedDocument(token, pageId);
System.out.println(base64Data.getData.getValue());
```

Instead of the base64 string, am getting output as [B@27e80064, which looks like some offset address.

Can you please let me know how to read the JABXElement element? getData.getValue() doesn't seem to work :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `[B@27e80064` is exactly what you'd expect to see with "System.out.println()" of a byte[] array.  The data is probably OK; it's just the "println()" that's surprising you.

Answer (score 1):

`getValue()` returns `byte[]`, so your println the array id not the content.

user `Arrays.toString(base64Data.getData.getValue()))` or 
`new String(base64Data.getData.getValue()))` to print the content.

You can also think over your design. I would keep the Data mapped as string in your jaxb bean, and add the method getDataDecoded() that would transform them to the byte[] using Base64 decoding, so no need for JAXBElement

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EpsBinaryEx {

    @XmlElement(name="ErrorString")
    String errorString;

    @XmlElement(name="ErrorNum")
    int errorNum;

    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    String encoded;

    @XmlTransient
    byte[] decoded;

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
        decoded = Base64.decode(encoded);
    }

    boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) {
        encoded = Base64.encode(decoded);
        return true;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return decoded;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] d) {
        decoded = d;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried the above two statements. Array.toString gave me just an array of numbers and new String() gave non-readable characters. I dont see the actual data from <Data> tag.

Can you elaborate on the overriding please?

Comment: but it is array of numbers, isn't. What is your goal actually. If it was correctly encoded as base64 than it cannot give non-readable characters (as they were no such in the encoded representation). You can try new String(byte[],"ISO-8859-1"), but it should not matter. As for the different approach I will edit the answer.

Comment: Am sorry if I wasn't clear in my explanation earlier.
As you see, the webservice am referring to gives data in xml format. The <Data> tag has a Base64 string. My goal is to read this string from the <Data> tag and then call a Base64.decode function to decode this string and create a PDF file.

Comment: I have done these conversions before but have never worked on EpsBinaryEx and JAXBElement<byte[]>. 
I tried the your method to override. I got an error for the statement encoded = Base64.encode(decoded); It said "Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to String". I changed the type of encode to byte[] and I ended up with getting the address of array again.

Comment: it was a fake Base64 class I dont know which implementation you are using, there must be some similar method, for example encodeBase64String for apache Base64